# LoopJ AndroidAsyncHttp error

Tags: android, android-async-http

Can anyone explain why this peace of code is not working?
I checked everything as in some sample online and I have the feeling I am missing something.
Thanks!

```
                    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                    params.put("d", dataVarAll);

                    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

                    client.get(" http://10.0.0.89/Data/D", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onStart() {
                            // called before request is started
                            consoleText.setText("Start...");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
                            // called when request is retried
                            consoleText.setText("Retry");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2, Throwable arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            consoleText.setText(new String(arg2));
                            Log.v("FAILURE: ", (new String(arg2)));
                            //consoleText.setText(arg1.toString());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            consoleText.setText(new String(arg2));
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I see the first error is the space in the URL:
This:

```
client.get(" http://10.0.0.89/Data/D", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()
```

To this:

```
client.get("http://10.0.0.89/Data/D", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()
```